# How can I print a multi line result using PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

```
PROCEDURE A(
...
BEGIN
stmt := 'select * from '||src;
execute immediate stmt;
dbms_output.put_line(??);
END A;
```

Comment: @OMG: The results of calling this PL/SQL procedure are already redirected to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the structure of the table named in "src" when writing the code then you can do this:

```
PROCEDURE A IS
...
  l_cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  stmt := 'select * from '||src;
  open l_cur for stmt;
  loop
    fetch l_cur into ??; -- record or list of variables that matches columns of "src"
    exit when l_cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(??);
  end loop;
  close l_cur;
END A;
```

If you will not know the structure until run time then you will need to use the [DBMS_SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_sql.htm#BABEDAHF) package, which is very powerful but not simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure wether this is working with your "execute immediate stmt" approach, but with static Sql, following is working for me:

```
  for my_result in
  (
    select * from my_table tbl
     where ...
     order by tbl.my_id_col
  ) loop

    dbms_output.put_line(my_result.field1 || ', ' || my_result.field2 || ...);

  end loop;
```